# In custom Terraform provider's tests, can I load another provider?

Tags: terraform

I have a custom Terraform provider which works well.

I am using `github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/helper/resource.Test` for my tests, but there I need a resource from another official provider.

How to load it?

Answer (score 0):

One way I've found is to import the provider's code to call its `Provider()` func.

Not ideal, but it works.